# Control two RGB LED Strips from Raspberry pi

Tags: pi-3, ws2812

I've connected two rgb strips(WS2812B) to raspberry pi. Each strip consists of 60 LEDs. The first strip data line is connected to GPIO pin number 18 & Second strip data line is connected to GPIO pin number 12. I'm using [strandtest.py](https://github.com/richardghirst/rpi_ws281x/blob/master/python/examples/strandtest.py) to control my strip. Initially I've used 12 as my pin number in the code then the second strip glows up. But Now if I use 18 as my pin number in the code then both of the strips starts to glow. How to control single strip at once?

Comment: How are you powering the strips?

Comment: I've connected a common power source to both the strips that is connected to an external power supply

Answer (score 1):

Now I've connected both the strips in series. This code worked for me:

```
import board
import neopixel
pixels = neopixel.NeoPixel(board.D18,120)

    for i in range(0,119):
       if i<=59:
          pixels[i] = (0,255,0)
       else:
          pixels[i] = (255,0,0)
    pixels.show()
```

Comment: clearly your original code was buggy